HKAuthorizationStatus for HKWorkoutRouteTypeIdentifier Always Returning .notDetermined After Granting Access
I am using HKHealthStore to request authorization for both HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier and HKWorkoutRouteTypeIdentifier. After the authorization is granted, I am trying to check the authorization status using authorizationStatus(for:), but it always returns HKAuthorizationStatus(rawValue: 0) (which corresponds to .notDetermined). Despite successfully granting access, the status does not reflect the change.
Here’s the code I’m using:
let h = HKHealthStore()
h.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: [HKObjectType.workoutType(), HKSeriesType.workoutRoute()]) { success, error in
    print("Request Authorization: \(success) - \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
    print("Authorization Status: \(h.authorizationStatus(for: HKSeriesType.workoutRoute()))")
}

What could be causing the HKAuthorizationStatus to remain .notDetermined even after I have granted the necessary permissions?
Thanks so much.
I added import HealthKit and NSHealthShareUsageDescription , NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription also.
